# MySQL: How to get five posts from each user?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I want to select users from one table, and check for `id` in the other by setting `LIMIT 5` for each.

Here's what I have, but I can't reuse, the `a.id` in the 2nd union

```
SELECT a.id AS USER,
       p.id AS post_id
FROM (
        (SELECT a.id
         FROM `user` a
         WHERE a.date=...)
      UNION
        (SELECT p.id
         FROM `post` p
         WHERE p.user_id=a.id LIMIT 5)`` `) AS post
```

Thank you, aloha

Comment: Normally if you want to look at values in one table and see if they exist in another you would use a join. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe give examples of your source data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: i want to get only 5 posts from each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query might look like below:

**Main Query:**

```
SELECT 
t.userID,
t.postID
FROM 
(
         SELECT
          user.id AS userID,
          post.id AS postID,
          IF (@prev = post.user_id ,@cn := @cn + 1 ,@cn := 0) SL,
          @prev := post.user_id
        FROM (SELECT @cn := 0, @prev := 0) var,post
        INNER JOIN user ON user.id = post.user_id
        ORDER BY post.user_id) t
WHERE t.SL < 5;
```

***The query will pick 5 posts for each user.***

---

**TEST:**

Unable to add an SQL FIDDLE.

So here's some test data with schema to check the query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post`;
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('1', '71');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('2', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('3', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('4', '71');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('5', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('6', '71');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('7', '71');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('8', '71');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('9', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('10', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('11', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('12', '66');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('13', '71');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('14', '91');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('66');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('71');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('91');


SELECT 
*
FROM post;
```

**Result:**

```
id  user_id
1   71
2   66
3   66
4   71
5   66
6   71
7   71
8   71
9   66
10  66
11  66
12  66
13  71
14  91
```

`SELECT * FROM user;`

**Result:**

```
id
66
71
91
```

Total posts per user query:

```
SELECT 
user_id,
COUNT(*) totalPost
FROM post 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

**Result:**

```
user_id  totalPost
66         7
71         6
91         1
```

**Final Result:**

```
userID postID
66       2
66       3
66       5
66       12
66       11
71       1
71       13
71       8
71       7
71       6
91       14
```

Comment: Can I put `WHERE t.SL < 5 ` between ( .. ) t ? Because I need to union another table to this...

Comment: No mate! You have to use this result set if you want to union with another table. Just ensure that this works for you.

Comment: So I will need to have `WHERE t.SL < 5 ` at the end of my select no matter how many unions I have?

Comment: It would be great if you share those queries which will be the part of the `UNION`.

Comment: what about using `HAVING COUNT(...) < 5` instead?

Comment: Okay let me clear a thing first. If a user has less than 5 posts then don't you want those posts into the final resultset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108291/discussion-between-1000111-and-aloha-mate).